# Paw Basic Auth line break character

Tags: paw-app

There seems to be a bug with Basic Auth in Paw. The password field is added a \n character to the end of the password I enter and breaks my authentication on the server side. You can even see the extra line after the password in this screenshot. I've also confirmed in my server-side code that there is indeed a newline character (\n) appended to the string.

http://note.io/12BJA6m

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you added a newline character after the password. Edit the password field, select all, and type the password again.

*(Though, I agree the field shouldn't accept newlines, I'll file a bug for that.)*